# jQuery find non specific elements with certain attribute

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to call non specific elements with a certain attribute? I know you can search for a div for example with a set attribute.

```
$('div[data-snap-ignore="true"]');
```

But I have various elements that have the attribute data-snap-ignore that are not always divs, they can be sections, uls, buttons, all sorts really. However the following doesn't work.

```
$('[data-snap-ignore="true"]');
```

Comment: `$('[data-snap-ignore="true"]');` works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/ZMDa2/

Comment: it should work fine with your current implementation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `*` to include all types, although it might need that.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUqEQ/)**

```
$('*[data-snap-ignore="true"]');
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this - have you tried the demo with asterisk omitted? ) It works the same actually.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer, it might not be working for OP, as you can see in his post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for elements just *having* an attribute (without any specific value to target), drop the value part:

```
$('[data-snap-ignore]');
```

Otherwise (if you're targeting elements with `data-snap-ignore` set to `true`) it should work fine with the code given - no asterisk's required.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use filter()

```
$('*').filter(function(){return $(this).data('myAttr') == true ;});
```

Or just: `$('[data-myAttr]')`

Or

```
$(':data').each(function(){ // your condition });;       // All elements with data  
$(':not(:data)').each(function{}()); // All elements without data
```